# PHP Is it possible to skip two or more iterations?

Tags: php, for-loop, continue

I am aware we can skip the next iteration with [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) in a for loop. Anyway to skip the next x loops (2 or more)?

Comment: For reference continue does not skip the next iteration, it ends the current one.

Comment: You can try defining an extra integer, set it to the amount of loops you want to skip and have an `if ( y < 0) { continue; }` type of thing

Comment: You can try to use continue; and i+=10; to skip more iterations?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you would need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually can't, you can do a dirty trick like

```
for ($i=0; $i<99; $i++){
    if(someCondition) {
        $i = $i + N; // This will sum N+1 because of the $i++ in the for iterator (that fire when the new loop starts)
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating with a for loop (as opposed to a foreach loop) you could do something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$numLoops; $i++) {
    if(condition()) {
        $i+= $numLoopsToSkip;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add one less to *i*. Adding 0 would still interrupt the current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example, you can define the amount of times you want to loop as you want as `$y`

```
<?php
y = 5;

while (true) {
    // do something
    if (y > 0) {
        y--;
        continue;
    }
    // do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this will generate an ugly loop, ```y``` is never decreased, so it will always be > 0

Comment: @GummaMocciaro *cough*

Answer (score 0):

Coming soon in PHP 'X'  ;-)

```
continue += x;
```

Comment: If this is even a good idea (reference: Edsger W. Dijkstra), I hope it would be this simple.